# Spring Boot, MockMVC and MessageSource

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc

so here's a very basic spring-boot project with just 6 classes.

https://github.com/paranoiabla/spring-boot-mockmvc

The setup is pretty basic and there's only one test-case which is failing. The exception I get is

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'custom.link' for locale 'en'.
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:159)
at org.test.MyController.home(MyController.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
```

And I belive this is because `SpringApplicationContextLoader` line `255`, method `addMockServletContext` creates a `MockServletContext` by calling the constructor that only accepts path. As a result inside the `MockServletContext` the `ResourceLoader` is initialized with `DefaultResourceLoader`, which will lookup for resources in the classpath. This way if I have a `ReloadableResourceMessageResolver` and my property files are in `/WEB-INF/messages/base.properties` it will never find them because `/WEB-INF/messages/base.properties` gets transformed to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/messages/base.properties` which is not found in the classpath by the `ReloadableMessageSourceResolver`. I think when creating the `MockServletContext` should be able to explicitly pass the `FileSystemResourceLoader`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `WEN-INF` should be `WEB-INF`

although I didn't check it fixes your problem.

Comment: Hi Johny, where did you see `WEN-INF`

Comment: Sorry, I saw it in the code - it was unintentional typo only in this project. I changed it but even with `WEB-INF` the problem stays.